# I Have issue in flutter slider

Tags: flutter, android-studio, slider

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx53O.png)
i want to build image slider like this from the left start of phone
but i have getting issue in slider my slider is starting from center of the page in flutter
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiKWv.png)
here is my code.

```
  CarouselSlider.builder(
                    itemCount: serviceDataList?.length,
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                      height: 100.0,
                      enlargeCenterPage: false,

             
                      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                   
                      autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(
                          milliseconds: 800),
            
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (context, i, id){
                      return Container(
                        width: 100,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(
                                sliderDataList.isEmpty ? '' : sliderDataList[i]['mslider_img']),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        // child:
                        //     Image(
                        //   image: NetworkImage(
                        //       sliderDataList[i]['mslider_img']),
                        //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        // ),
                      );
                     
                    }
                ),
```

I Just Want help In This Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `viewportFraction` in `CarouselOptions` to smaller number that match container fixed width `viewportFraction: 0.2` for example & add  `padEnds: false`